# Get selected index of Datagrid

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, datagrid

I want to know, how do I get the selected index, if I change the selection of a datagrid row. I´ve searched a lot and have found only the [Adobe site](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/events/DataGridEvent.html)

This is what I think is the right way:

```
myGrid.addEventListener(DataGridEvent.ITEM_FOCUS_IN, datagridchanged);
```

```
//DataGrid Changed Listener function
private function datagridchanged (e:DataGridEvent):void{
  trace(e.selectedIndex); //Don`t know if .selectedIndex is correct
}
```

But nothing works, if someone could help me please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to know which item has been selected, you can listen to `Event.CHANGE` on your DataGrid.

Like this, for example:

```
mygrid.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, onGridSelectedItem);

function onGridSelectedItem(e:Event):void{
   var selected:int = mygrid.selectedIndex;
   var item:Object = mygrid.selectedItem;
}
```

Comment: I think this is the first step, the next and more important step has to be:What is the index of the item

Comment: What do you mean? You datagrid holds the index of the selected item in its `selectedIndex` property. `mygrid.selectedIndex` is the index of the item. And `mygrid.selectedItem` is the item itself.

Comment: You are right, I did not mention that there is this property Thank you